# Is exp an older form of expt?

Tags: common-lisp

I've found this in Tanimoto's *The Elements of Artificial Intelligence Using Common Lisp*:

```
; sample formula:
;
;  d     2
;  --   x  + 2x
;  dx

; represented by f0 as follows:
(setf  f0 '(d (+ (exp x 2) (* 2 x)) x))
```

Shouldn't that be `expt` rather than `exp`? This program, [LEIBNIZ.lisp](ftp://ftp.cs.washington.edu/homes/tanimoto/ai/LEIBNIZ.CL) uses `exp` in many places where I think it should be `expt`. What am I missing? Is this just a history problem? Or is this an error?

Answer (score 7):

The behaviors of **expt** and **exp** are described in the HyperSpec entry, [**EXP**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_exp_e.htm), [**EXPT**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_exp_e.htm).  **(exp n)** returns *e*<sup>n</sup>, whereas **(expt x y)** returns x<sup>y</sup>.  This is in accord with your understanding.

> exp and expt perform exponentiation.
>
> exp returns e raised to the power number, where e is the base of the
>   natural logarithms. exp has no branch cut.
>
> expt returns base-number raised to the power power-number. If the
>   base-number is a rational and power-number is an integer, the
>   calculation is exact and the result will be of type rational;
>   otherwise a floating-point approximation might result. For expt of a
>   complex rational to an integer power, the calculation must be exact
>   and the result is of type (or rational (complex rational)).

Tanimoto knows this too.  In the glossary, on page 519 (first edition), there are descriptions of Common Lisp's **exp** and **expt**. Here, however, these symbols are being used in a different way.  Tanimoto is developing a symbolic algebra system, and is using the symbol **exp** in representing exponential expressions.  In the line

```
(setf  f0 '(d (+ (exp x 2) (* 2 x)) x))
```

the value of **f0** is just the *list* **(d (+ (exp x 2) (* 2 x)) x))**. It's not code that's getting executed.  The point is that it is an algebraic expression.  It's just a nested list of symbols and numbers.  **d** isn't a function defined in Common Lisp at all.  Later, on page 99 (first edition), Tanimoto defines some symbolic differentiation rules:

```
(setq exp0-rule '(
  simplify
  (exp (? e1) 0)
  1
  exp0-rule
  ) )
```

```
(setq exp1-rule '(
  simplify
  (exp (? e1) 1)
  e1
  exp1-rule
  ) )
```

These are based on the mathematical rules described on page 96 where:

EXP0-RULE: *x*<sup>0</sup> = 1
        EXP1-RULE: *x*<sup>1</sup> = *x*

Comment: I think I understand now. IOW, don't think of `exp` as the CL function `exp`. It's just maybe a bad choice of dummy symbols. BTW, I'm on 2nd ed of Tanimoto.

Comment: I don't think it's really a terrible choice, but there is some potential for confusion, definitely.  There's bound to be some overlap in a symbolic representation of formulae and a programming language that provides math functions.

Comment: Yes, got it now. But I think we're on different editions of Tanimoto. Page numbers don't match. Me, 2nd ed.

Comment: @147pm yeah, I updated my answer to mention first edition (which I assume it is, since it's 1990 and does not mention any other edition).